# How to retrieve user data from fire store

Tags: reactjs

I need to fetch the user data and display it. I am getting an error now that says

> TypeError: this.unsubscribe is not a function

and when I initialise it as a normal variable like const db, then I get another error

> Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string

```
import React from "react";
import { auth, firestore } from "../../firebase/firebase.utils";

export default class UserPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user: {}
  };

  unsubscribe = null;

  componentDidMount() {
    const user = auth.currentUser;

    this.unsubscribe = firestore
      .collection("users")
      .doc(user)
      .onSnapshot(doc => {
        this.setState = {
          user: doc.data()
        };
      });
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.user.name}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> when I insinalise it as a normal variable like const db

Not quite sure what you mean by this, but if you're getting an error about the type of `unsubscribe`, I suggest using `console.log` right before you call it to view its value.

Bear in mind that `componentWillMount` happens in [the lifecycle](https://programmingwithmosh.com/javascript/react-lifecycle-methods/) **before** `componentDidMount` (hence the names *will* and *did*). I suspect that's one of your problems: you try to call unsubscribe before setting the value.

With regard to your other error about the `doc` call, it's likely referring to:

```
...
.collection("users")
      .doc(user)                     <-- this line
      .onSnapshot(doc => {
        this.setState = {
          us
...
```

As the error output states, that `user` variable (the first argument of `doc`) must be a string, and it can't be an empty string.

I don't see `user` anywhere in your code, so I expect that it's currently the value `undefined`. You could access `this.state.user` here, but I'd strongly advise against it since you subsequently set that state in the call (probably cause an infinite loop).

What is your end goal? What have you tried to resolve these two issues? Maybe adding that to your question would help us assist you better.

Comment: I used user in the code (const user = auth.currentUser)  as a current user. my goal is to fix the error that unsubscribes is not a function, what do u think that caused?